# I have a keystore on a physical piece of paper, can I use it to restore ethereum?

Tags: paper-wallets

Hos is this done most simply. Currently I use MIST/Ethereum wallet, but whatever is good for me.

Comment: When you way a keystore what do you mean by that? Did you print a UTC file (like the ones in [here](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Accounts,_Addresses,_Public_And_Private_Keys,_And_Tokens))? Or is it a sequence of hexadecimal characters?